# Error putting item in DynamoDB with AWS Java SDK and Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using hadoop 2.7, hadoop-core version 1.1.2 and AWS Java SDK 1.10.50.

When I attempt to put an item on dynamoDB, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.SdkConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.getKeepAliveDuration(SdkConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.java:48)
```

What I found is that this error is due to a conflict of the AWS SDK and the HttpCore version.

Running in my code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class";
System.out.println(resource);
```

The output is:

```
jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar!/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class
```

Indicating that it is still using a conflicting version.

But on my pom.xml, I've added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Trying to force a compatible version with the SDK, but my code still uses the conflicting version.

Anyone know how can I force my application to use the non-conflicting version of HttpCore and HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency on the version of httpclient you need and [exclude the httpclient transient dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) from the dependency that pulls in version 4.2.5. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to determine the where to add the exclusion.